# Unverified users could login to app. How to prevent it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

The verification implemented well, and i get the relevant email, but even when 
i do not click on verification link, i succeed to login to my app.

How can i fix it, please?

My verification implementation is like this:

```
final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user.isEmailVerified())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email is verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email is not verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            user.sendEmailVerification()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            // Re-enable button
                            //  findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(true);

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(AccountTypeActivity.this//EmailPasswordActivity.this
                                        ,"Verification email sent to " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(AccountTypeActivity.this//EmailPasswordActivity.this
                                        ,  "Failed to send verification email.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm a stupid.
The solution is to put this if else to login page...
Did it, and all is works!!!

```
   if (user.isEmailVerified())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email is verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 openmainactivity();
            } else
            {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Verify your email!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mauth.signout();
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you enforce access for verified emails in your server or security rules. Front end validation is not enough.